# errors in .obj files while building the source code in visual studio

Tags: azerothcore

The first steps when using CMake works like a charm. No error shows up and everything generates as it should, but when I try to build it in Visual Studio I get 11 errors and 3 warnings.

so errors are in .obj files and not sure how to solve them. The first Error is in Main.obj in Authserver project, and the second one is in the main.obj in the worldserver project

Error number 1:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol SSLeay_version referenced in function "int __cdecl ace_main_i(int,char * * const)" (?ace_main_i@@YAHHQEAPEAD@Z)  authserver  C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\authserver\Main.obj 1

Error number 2:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol SSLeay_version referenced in function "int __cdecl ace_main_i(int,char * * const)" (?ace_main_i@@YAHHQEAPEAD@Z)  worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\Main.obj    1

The next 4 errors are in the shared.lib(OpenSSL crypto.obj) file in the worldserver project.

Error number 1:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_num_locks referenced in function "void __cdecl OpenSSLCrypto::threadsSetup(void)" (?threadsSetup@OpenSSLCrypto@@YAXXZ)    worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(OpenSSLCrypto.obj)   1

Error number 2:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_set_locking_callback referenced in function "void __cdecl OpenSSLCrypto::threadsSetup(void)" (?threadsSetup@OpenSSLCrypto@@YAXXZ) worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(OpenSSLCrypto.obj)   1

Error number 3:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_THREADID_set_numeric referenced in function "void __cdecl threadIdCallback(struct crypto_threadid_st *)" (?threadIdCallback@@YAXPEAUcrypto_threadid_st@@@Z)   worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(OpenSSLCrypto.obj)   1

Error number 4:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol CRYPTO_THREADID_set_callback referenced in function "void __cdecl OpenSSLCrypto::threadsSetup(void)" (?threadsSetup@OpenSSLCrypto@@YAXXZ)    worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(OpenSSLCrypto.obj)   1

The next 3 errors are in shared.lib(ARC4.obj) shared.lib(HMACSHA1.obj) files.

Error number 1 ARC4.obj file:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init referenced in function "public: __cdecl ARC4::ARC4(unsigned int)" (??0ARC4@@QEAA@I@Z)    worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(ARC4.obj)    1

Error number 2 HMACSHA1 file:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol HMAC_CTX_init referenced in function "struct hmac_ctx_st * __cdecl HMAC_CTX_new(void)" (?HMAC_CTX_new@@YAPEAUhmac_ctx_st@@XZ)    worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(HMACSHA1.obj)    1

Error number 3 HMACSHA1 file:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol HMAC_CTX_cleanup referenced in function "void __cdecl HMAC_CTX_free(struct hmac_ctx_st *)" (?HMAC_CTX_free@@YAXPEAUhmac_ctx_st@@@Z)  worldserver C:\Azerothcore\Build\src\server\worldserver\shared.lib(HMACSHA1.obj)    1

Answer (score 5):

fixed the issue, had a corrupted version of OpenSSL, so when running through Cmake it didn't notice it, but visual studio do, so removed OpenSSL, got a fresh install and did rerun Cmake and now it did build just fine

Comment: Hi Can you share the OpenSSL latest with all binaries which is not having errors. I mean clean compiling bulid